# create-react-app typescript - blank page on yarn start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im trying to start my create-react-app but it just shows a blank page... [image]

I tried adding `homepage: "."` to my `package.json` but nothing helps. Does anyone know how to fix this? Every react project I try it shows up blank. `npm ls react` also only shows one version

Console Returns:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view solspinnr in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.70:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.

assets by path static/ 1.51 MiB
  asset static/js/bundle.js 1.5 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset static/js/node_modules_web-vitals_dist_web-vitals_js.chunk.js 6.88 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
  asset static/media/logo.6ce24c58023cc2f8fd88fe9d219db6c6.svg 2.57 KiB [emitted] (auxiliary name: main)
asset index.html 1.67 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 546 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 31.4 KiB 16 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.37 MiB 95 modules
modules by path ./src/ 18.2 KiB
  modules by path ./src/*.css 8.82 KiB
    ./src/index.css 2.72 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css 1.37 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/App.css 2.72 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/App.css 2 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./src/*.tsx 4.39 KiB
    ./src/index.tsx 1.83 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/App.tsx 2.56 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./src/reportWebVitals.ts 1.4 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./src/logo.svg 3.61 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.65.0 compiled successfully in 4764 ms
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Open in other browsers as well. check dev console to see if anything rendered inside of `#root`

Comment: Ah yes. The browser console: `TypeError: EventEmitter is not a constructor
    js emitter.js:2`

Comment: Look in the browser console also (open the dev tools pane in the browser.)

Comment: Still doesnt work in other browsers

Comment: Its this emmiter.js error but cant find any file in my dir

Comment: its in my yarn.lock though eventemitter3@

Comment: Can you post the full call stack for this error?